# Is the sentence "Je me sentais de la même façon que tu te sens maintenant" correct?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps

Is "Je me sentais de la même façon que tu te sens maintenant" correct? I want it to mean "I felt the same way that you're feeling now" Can I use "en ce moment" at the end instead of "Maintenant", and if there's anything wrong can you explain?

Comment: This sounds ok to me, as a native speaker, and this sounds better that what the current answers propose. Also "en ce moment" is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Même que je suis américain, je préfère la phrase dans la question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct since there is no mistake, but is not the good way to express it. If you are tied to the litterate translation, you can use it. If you just want to express it, you could use :

> J'avais le même sentiment que tu as maintenant

"Que tu te" is heavy in french and won't be widely used in familiar language except in the *subjonctif* tense which is not very used itself.

You can even remove the second verb and write :

> J'avais le même sentiment que toi à présent

And yes, *en ce moment* can replace *maintenant* like *à présent* did in my second translation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say:
  "J'ai éprouvé la même chose que toi maintenant"

"éprouver" means "to have the feeling that" and is more idiomatic than "avoir le sentiment". You could use "se sentir" but "se sentir" is less precise as it can refer to physical sensations as well as sentimental feelings.